# Diffrence between Capture rate and Frame rate?

Tags: android, capture, frame-rate, android-mediarecorder

`setCaptureRate`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setCaptureRate%28double%29

`setVideoFrameRate`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setVideoFrameRate%28int%29

What is the diffrence between `setCaptureRate()` and `setVideoFrameRate()` API's in `MediaRecorder` Class of Android?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation for `setCaptureRate()`:

> Set video frame capture rate. This can be used to set a different
>   video frame capture rate than the recorded video's playback rate. This
>   method also sets the recording mode to time lapse. In time lapse video
>   recording, only video is recorded. Audio related parameters are
>   ignored when a time lapse recording session starts, if an application
>   sets them.

let's use 0.1fps as parameter so 
setCaptureRate(0.1) means 1 frame per 10 seconds. 0.001 would be 1 frame per 100 seconds. 
I've found example: [here](https://github.com/mobapptuts/android_camera2_api_video_app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/mobapptut/com/camera2videoimage/Camera2VideoImageActivity.java)

and  `setVideoFrameRate()` is what you know:

> Sets the frame rate of the video to be captured
>    `25fps, 30fps, 60fps -`

You can see difference also in paramater. `setCaptureRate()` can accept decimals but `setVideoFrameRate()` works only with integers.